# upload picture to google app engine and save it till a request will come

Tags: android, image, google-app-engine, file-upload, entity

I am trying to make an application that will use the google app engine server , the user will send data with a picture to the server. The server will save the data and the picture in a datastore(thats what i am aiming for).

i've managed to make the server work without the picture, and everything works like a charm.
I am able to save text in the datastore and when a request comes from a client the server will send the data. now i want to add the abillity of sending a picture and store it in the datastore.
Before the user send the file I am converting the file into a string, and send it, in the server I get the whole string but the problem is that the string is too big, and the datastore entity is limited to 500 bytes.

I know I can split the string into small cuncks and save it, I dont really like this but if there is no other choise i can use it.

ive seen some examples that i can use blob but i dont really know how to and if i have to, if the answer is using blob do i have to change the datastore? and plz post some example codes of handling the data with blob.

i will upload my code if it is necessary.
thnx rajedbuli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was surprised when you said your entity is limited to 500 bytes. That's the maximum size of a key. I assume you are storing the string as the key, but instead you should store it in a separate column. Here's a little python sample data model:

```
class Image(ndb.Model):
    filename = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    size = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    pic = ndb.BlobProperty(required=True)
```

Above, I used type BlobProperty for the contents of the picture. Since entities are limited to 1MB in size, and there's a little overhead for the other fields in the table plus metadata, I usually some code like this to save a new image:

```
if size > 990000:
    raise Exception('File too large: %s' % size)
obj = Image()  # create new Image object
obj.filename = 'your_filename.png'
obj.size = your_filesize
obj.pic = your_picture_contents
obj.put()  # save the object
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should take a look at Google Cloud Storage as well.  You could store all your pictures there and put a reference into your datastore.

The datastore certainly can store blobs, but I wonder whether GCS is better suited to the purpose.  An important advantage is that client devices can perform HTTP operations directly to GCS servers, so the picture could be stored as a single, simple operation and you wouldn't have to convert the picture to text, which seems really yucky to me (unless these are just tiny thumbnails).

(GCS would be particularly well suited for pictures that are going to be downloaded many times - it can function as a CDN - but you haven't given any indication that this is the case in your app.)

Comment: thnx m8, i've been reading about the GCS and i can use it too but i did something else. the first comment from user was helpful.

Comment: i think the GCS is better option to look for.. in the long run with much blob in the database is not suggested..